# Falling into a black hole emitter vs observer

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems

Let's say we are working with the Schwarzschild metric and we have an emitter of light falling into a Schwarzschild black hole.

Suppose we define the quantity $$u=t- v$$ where $$dv/dr= 1/(1-r_{s}/r)$$ where $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius. What is the $u$ as observed by the emitter? I just need a *definition of $u_e$*. I have problems identifying the quantities as measured by an observer at large $r$ and that of the emitter. Would I be right at least to say that $$t_{e}=\tau$$ the proper time? Many thanks.

---

In fact, I've been told that

$$du_o/d\tau=du_e/d\tau$$

Why is it?

---

My apologies for leaving out a subscript $e$ in the question. It has been added.

Comment: What are $u$ and $v$?  Whose proper time is $\tau$?  I think we need more background to the setup of your question.

Comment: @NathanReed: $u,v$ are defined in the question...! I don't know whose proper time that is, unfortunately. I am only given the metric! I have already included all the info I know...

Comment: No, $u, v$ are not defined in the question. :)  You've given a couple of relationships between $u, v$ and the coordinates $r, t$, but I still have no idea what you intend $u, v$ to actually mean.  And how can you not know whose proper time you're talking about?  It's your question, after all.  Sorry, but you're going to have to do a better job of asking what you want to know.  Where is all of this coming from - a textbook, a homework problem?  Give us more context.

Comment: @NathanReed: :) It is taken from some old notes. Let's assume the proper time is that of the emitter and the observer located at a constant large r.

Comment: If you define $u$ by your first two equations, then $u,r$ form a system of [Outgoing Eddington Finkelstein coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington%E2%80%93Finkelstein_coordinates).  $u$=const describes an outgoing null ray, which I guess in your picture is the path which represents a light pulse emitted by the emitter and received by the observer who sits fixed at large $r$.  Like Nathan though, I'm not sure whose proper time we're talking about.

Comment: Maybe they intend you to work out $(u_e(\tau), r_e(\tau))$ for the infalling emitter and  $(u_o(\tau), r_o(\tau))$ for the asymptotic observer (easy!), then compare the derivatives w.r.to proper time?